# jq: how does any() real work in array context?

Tags: jq

jq produces unexpected results when `any()` is called in this context `any(array[]==val)`

I'm not sure how `jq` calculates these results:

```
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [1,2][]|. == .) '
false
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [2,1][]|. == .) '
false
# or
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [1,2][] == .) '
true
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [2,1][] == .) '
false
```

I'd expect `true` in all cases?

when using `==` in explicit expression, the results are as expected.

```
$ jq -n '([2,2][]) == ([1,2][])'
false
false
true
true
$ jq -n '([2,2][]) == ([2,1][])'
true
true
false
false
```

How can it be explained?

Comment: I'll note that changing #1 to `jq -n '[2,2] | any( ([1,2][]|.) == .) '` "fixes" it, but the same change doesn't affect the output of #2. I suspect that whatever explains the difference between #3 and #4 similarly explains the difference between the explicitly parenthesized #1 and #2.

Comment: According to the [implementation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L180-L182), `[2,2] | any([2,1][] == .)` should be translated to `[2,2] | (isempty(.[] | ([2,1][] == .) or empty) | not)`, but only the latter [correctly evaluates](https://jqplay.org/s/tkOBXhG8tqu) to `true`.

Comment: A simplified version showing the phenomenon could be `jq -n '[1] | any(true)'` vs `jq -n '[1] | any(true, true)'` for `any/1`, and `jq -n 'any(1; true)'` vs `jq -n 'any(1; true, true)'` for `any/2`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is a bug in jq 1.6. I compiled master version which gives correct result :

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6-159-gcff5336
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [1,2][]|. == .) '
true
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [2,1][]|. == .) '
true
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [1,2][] == .) '
true
$ jq -n '[2,2] | any( [2,1][] == .) '
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in version 1.6 that has been fixed long ago:

```
$jq -n '[2,2]|any([2,1][]|(.==.)|debug)' 
["DEBUG:",true]
["DEBUG:",true]
false


$ jqMaster -n '[2,2]|any([2,1][]|(.==.)|debug)' 
["DEBUG:",true]
true
```

This fix is one of the most important reasons it is such a shame that version 1.6 is still the most recent “official” version.